# Is there a way to append to a json object in a file?

Tags: json

I am using a file to hold json data that my program is generating. The structure is something like this:

```
{"allData" : {
    "data1": [{"d": 10}, {"d": 20}, {"d": 30}],
    "data2": [{"d": 100}, {"d": 200}, {"d": 300}],
    "data3": [{"d": 1000}, {"d": 2000}, {"d": 3000}]
    }
}
```

I am generating and writing data almost constantly. I only occasionally need to read the data from the file to use in the program.

The problem is that whenever I want to add some new data to one of the data members of the allData object from the program I have to read in the whole object from a file and store it into a json object in memory, access the data member, append a new piece of data, and then write the whole object back to the file.

I would like to be able to add data to the file more efficiently than that by bypassing bringing the whole object into memory. I think it would be better to just open the file for appending and add a piece of data to it. However, I don't think that would work because appending to the end of the file would screw up the format of the json.

My initial thought is to create three separate json files, data1.json, data2.json, and data3.json with just the objects in them, like this:

```
data1.json
{"d": 10}
{"d": 20}
{"d": 30}
```

And then for the few times that I need to read the data for use in my program, I would open the files and reconstruct the original json object.

Is there a way to append to a json object in a file? What would be the preferred way of adding to a json object in a file? Is there another file format other than json that does allow this type of behavior?

Comment: "I am generating and writing data almost constantly"

This sounds like a use case for a database; any reason you need to use flat files?

Comment: Sounds like a good use of just flat files: data1.txt, data2.txt, etc. and then when you need it as json, just generate the json on the fly from all the files.